# Destroy action deleting from wrong table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a users model that can have many holidays through a rich join table.. My destroy statement on my view is deleting from the holidays table and NOT the user_holidays table as it should.. see below:

```
class HolidaysController < ApplicationController
  def destroy 
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) 
  @user_holiday = @user.holidays.find(params[:id]) 
  @user_holiday.destroy 
  redirect_to @user 
  end
end
```

Heres the view button:

```
<% @user.holidays.each do |hld| %>
                  <td><%= hld.name %></td>
                  <td><%= hld.date %></td>
                <td>
                    <%= button_to('Destroy', user_holiday_path(@user, hld), :method => 'delete', :class => 'btn btn-large btn-primary') %>
```

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :user_holidays 
has_many :holidays, :through => :user_holidays

class UserHoliday < ActiveRecord::Base 
attr_accessible :holiday_id, :user_id 
belongs_to :user 
belongs_to :holiday 

class Holiday < ActiveRecord::Base 
attr_accessible :name, :date 
has_many :user_holidays 
has_many :users, :through => :user_holidays
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@user.user_holidays` instead of `@user.holidays`

```
@user_holiday = @user.user_holidays.where(holiday_id: params[:id])
```

Answer (score 0):

(my bad didn't read you question properly)

```
 @user = User.find(params[:user_id]) 
 @user.holidays.delete(@user.holidays.find(params[:id]))
```